# applying a var to an if statement jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to apply a var to a statement if its conditions are met, this syntax isn't throwing errors but its not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var action_is_post = false;
      //stuff here
    $(this).ready(function () {
        if ($("#stepDesc0").is(".current")) {
        action_is_post = true;     
        }
    });
  //stuff here
</script>
```

should I use something other than `.ready`? Do I even need the `$(this).ready(function ()...` part? I need it to apply the `var` when `#stepDesc0` has the class `current`.

$(document).ready(function(){
  var action_is_post = false;
  $("form").submit(function () {
    action_is_post = true;
  });

if ($("#stepDesc0").is(".current")) {
        var action_is_post = true;     
      }

 window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    if (!action_is_post)
      return 'Using the browsers back, refresh or close button will cause you to lose all form data. Please use the Next and Back buttons on the form.';
  }
});

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var action_is_post=$("#stepDesc0").is(".current");
  });
</script>
```

If you want the variable to be accessible outside the `$(document).ready(function(){...`, then you'll need to declare it outside the statement like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var action_is_post;

  $(document).ready(function(){
    action_is_post=$("#stepDesc0").is(".current");
  });
</script>
```

**HTML (in order to test it):**

```
<a href="javascript:alert(action_is_post);">Show value</a>
```

Comment: Should have posted all the code. It pertains to a form wizard, I have already disabled the onbeforeunload for the submit function, now I need to disable it for the first step of the wizard.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  var action_is_post = false;
  $("form").submit(function () {
    action_is_post = true;
  });
 
 $(this).ready(function () {
  if ($("#stepDesc0").is(".current")) {
  action_is_post = true;     
        }
    }); 
 
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
  function confirmExit()
  {
    if (!action_is_post)
      return 'Using the browsers back, refresh or close button will cause you to lose all form data. Please use the Next and Back buttons on the form.';
  }
});
</script>

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    var actionIsPost = $('#stepDesc0').is('.current'); 
    alert( actionIsPost );
});
```

If you are adding the `current` class to #stepDesc0 on an `event` then put the `.is` check in the event handler.